# Suppress Vue warnings in unit tests

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I am trying to suppress my warnings in my tests following the config listed here: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/config.html#silent, which is as follows:

```javascript
import { config } from '@vue/test-utils';

// this should actually be the default but the default is not working
config.silent = true;
```

However, I am still seeing the warning in the test results:

```
  TheQueue
✓ should show the queue bar if there are items queued
✓ should show the correct count of queued items in queued bar
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be 
overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a 
data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being 
mutated: "mdTemplateData"

found in

---> <MdTab>
       <MdContent>
         <MdTabs>
           <MdDrawer>
             <TheQueue> at src/components/the-queue/TheQueue.vue
               <Root>
```

It's worth noting that I do not see this error in normal usage of the app. This only pops up in tests (otherwise I would attempt to fix the actual suggested issue).

What am I doing wrong here and why can I not suppress these warning? Or am I misunderstanding what `silent` is supposed to do?

Comment: I am trying to silent Vue warnings in unit tests too, but as far as I understood by reading [`vue-test-utils` source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/blob/4c65dbd9a3e0496e92f01bc053bdb95a82546eac/packages/test-utils/src/wrapper.js#L456), this `silent` configuration attribute triggers only when you're using [`setProps`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setprops-props])method in your tests.

Comment: Any progress in this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: I know you asked it 6 months ago but I just see your question now, Hope it helps you

Answer (score 9):

According to the VueJS docs - https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/config.html#silent

> **silent**
>
> type: Boolean
>
> default: true
>
> It suppresses warnings triggered by Vue while mutating component's
>   observables (e.g. props). When set to false, all warnings are visible
>   in the console. This is a configurable way **which relies on
>   Vue.config.silent**.

**which relies on Vue.config.silent**, so all you need is to import `vue` package and set it's `config.silent` to `false`

```
import Vue from `vue`
Vue.config.silent = true;
```

I put a working example here in my Github, it's just a fork of official example but it doesn't show warnings during the tests.

https://github.com/al1b/vue-test-utils-getting-started

**For more information:**

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/38e967b8067441ff37cb3b923200023a6b842759/src/core/util/debug.js#L23):

```
  warn = (msg, vm) => {
    const trace = vm ? generateComponentTrace(vm) : ''

    if (config.warnHandler) {
      config.warnHandler.call(null, msg, vm, trace)
    } else if (hasConsole && (!config.silent)) {
      console.error(`[Vue warn]: ${msg}${trace}`)
    }
  }
```

Comment: For `@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest` You can put `silent: true` inside of the `jest.config.js` file in your root folder.