# How to get rid of Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _vm.myFcn is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

Following the [documentation](https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Observateurs), I have written a Vue component containing the following logic:

```js
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'

export default {
  [...]
  created () {
    this.debouncedOnSubmit = debounce(this.doSubmit, 1000)
  },
  [...]
```

The idea behind this is that my form calls the `debouncedOnSubmit` method upon form submission:

```html
        <button
          name="order-basket"
          type="submit"
          @click.prevent="debouncedOnSubmit"
        >
          Click me!
        </button>
```

Now, that code works fine in my application, as well as in my jest tests. For example, with the vue test utils, I can trigger the `click` event on that button and the relevant stuff that should happen upon clicking that button can be verified successfully.

However, I get the following annoying warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _vm.debouncedOnSubmit is not a function"
```

I partially understand why I get that warning. Indeed, I define `this.debouncedOnSubmit` in the `created()` hook. It's pretty likely that Jest does not understand the meaning of that variable, even though the `debounce` method returns a function.

How can make jest understand that `debouncedOnSubmit` is a function? What do I need to configure?

I do not want to disable the warnings, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53621142/suppress-vue-warnings-in-unit-tests), because I do want to keep a feedback on my doings in my tests. Most of time, the warnings are really helpful and I do not feel comfortable with the idea of switching them off. How can I write my code so that this warning is fixed?

### EDIT

- changing

```html
@click.prevent="debouncedOnSubmit"
```

to

```
@click.prevent="debouncedOnSubmit()"
```

does not change anything to the problem

- moving `debouncedOnSubmit` from the `created()` hook to the `computed` stuff like this

```js
debouncedOnSubmit: debounce(this.doSubmit, 1000)
```

throws the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'doSubmit' of undefined
```

- changing

```html
@click.prevent="debouncedOnSubmit"
```

to

```
@click.prevent="debouncedOnSubmit()"
```

**and** moving `debouncedOnSubmit` from the `created()` hook to the `computed` stuff like this

```js
debouncedOnSubmit () {
      const submit = this.doSubmit
      return debounce(submit, 1000)
    }
```

still makes my app and tests work, but I still end up with the same warning in my jest tests:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _vm.debouncedOnSubmit is not a function"
```

Comment: have you tried calling it with () e.g. @click.prevent="debouncedOnSubmit()", and maybe converted it to a computed function if that doesnt work

Comment: have a very similar issue. What was your solution?? I am trying to return $this.store.state.modules.post.image in a function in computed. it is coming from a vue-croppa with:  :initial-image="getImage". getImage, getImage.image and even getimage() in methods still returns this error.

Comment: I still have no solution to that problem whatsoever. Nothing works "cleanly". Currently, the app works, the tests pass, but I still have that annoying error message.

Answer (score 3):

Use `methods` property to define your functions

```
methods: {
 debouncedOnSubmit()
}
```

Comment: If I do that, then the `doSubmit` function never gets called. I tried both to get rid of the corresponding code in my `created` hook and to keep it, and at the same time to add the `debouncedOnSubmit` method to thte methods. In both cases, the `doSubmit` method never gets called.

Comment: I was running into this "_vm.myFunctionNameHere is not a function" issue in my code as well.  Same kind of symptoms as OP, the click handler worked, (and I could console.log from the handler and see it get called when I clicked on it) but then subsequently Vue emitted this warning.  This was the hint I needed, I'd written my click handler (copy pasta) as a computed property rather than a method.  Once it was a proper method all was good.

Comment: I think @LaurentMichel has two problems.  First  `debounceOnSubmit` needs to be a method.  Then `doSubmit` needs to be called correctly from that method (probably via `this.doSubmit`).  The example given of the `debounceSubmit` function from the "computed stuff" looks prefect, it just has to be a method.  Which is exactly what @Iman suggests.

Answer (score 1):

"TypeError: _vm.debouncedOnSubmit is not a function" means vuejs can not find any function in it's build-in functions with this name.

one thing that you miss is just putting your function in `Default Components Options` like:
`methods`, `computed`, `actions`

```
methods: {
   debouncedOnSubmit () {
   const submit = this.doSubmit
   return debounce(submit, 1000)
 }
}
```

then you can call your function without error

Comment: doesn't work either, for the same reason as for Vishal Pratap's proposition

Comment: @LaurentMichel use computed option instead of methods! i think your function is doing compute action